# I installed Storybook into a Gridsome project, and it has now broken the Gridsome build

Tags: vuejs2, babeljs, storybook, gridsome

The command `npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type vue` was used to install Storybook, now when I run `gridsome develop`, I get a heap of errors regarding `core-js`.

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 63 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                  11:29:51 AM

These dependencies were not found:

* core-js/modules/es6.array.filter in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/router.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/components/Image.js and 2 others
* core-js/modules/es6.array.for-each in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/head.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/router.js and 5 others
* core-js/modules/es6.array.from in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/directives/image.js
* core-js/modules/es6.array.index-of in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/utils/class.js
* core-js/modules/es6.array.is-array in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/router.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/utils/class.js
* core-js/modules/es6.array.map in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/entry.client.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/router.js
* core-js/modules/es6.function.name in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/entry.client.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/fetchPath.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.number.constructor in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/components/Link.js
* core-js/modules/es6.object.define-properties in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/router.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/components/Link.js and 2 others
* core-js/modules/es6.object.define-property in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/router.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/components/Link.js and 2 others
* core-js/modules/es6.object.keys in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/router.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/components/Image.js and 2 others
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.constructor in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/components/Link.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/utils/helpers.js
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.replace in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/utils/class.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/utils/helpers.js
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.search in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/entry.client.js
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/utils/class.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/utils/helpers.js
* core-js/modules/es6.string.ends-with in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/directives/image.js
* core-js/modules/es6.string.iterator in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/entry.client.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/directives/image.js
* core-js/modules/es6.string.link in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/head.js
* core-js/modules/es6.string.starts-with in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/entry.client.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/components/Link.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.string.trim in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/utils/class.js
* core-js/modules/es6.symbol in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/app.js
* core-js/modules/es7.object.get-own-property-descriptors in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/router.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/components/Link.js and 2 others
* core-js/modules/es7.symbol.async-iterator in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/app.js
* core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable in ./node_modules/gridsome/app/router.js, ./node_modules/gridsome/app/app.js and 7 others
```

The error does give the option to fix it by installing each of those specifically, but I don't think that should be required (and the install command doesn't work anyway)

I didn't have any custom babel configuration from what Gridsome provides when creating a new project, but after doing some searching, I have tried adding a `babel.config.js` file with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [ [ "@vue/app", { useBuiltIns: "entry" } ] ]
};
```

however that doesn't appear to help the issue at all.

I have created a repository on Github that replicates the issue: https://github.com/denno020/storybookBreakingGridsome

Can anyone shed some light as to why Storybook would break Gridsome?